# How to use macro in an anti-cheat protected MMO?

Tags: python, anti-cheat

In an MMORPG (Metin2) game, I need to click on certain places with the mouse, but the cheat protection prevents this. I can't even do this on the desktop when the game is open.

To be more specific, let's say I'm fishing in the game;

1. While fishing, bait is attached to the fishing line by pressing the
   "1" button first.
2. Then press the "space" button to shake the fishing rod.
3. After a while, a fish icon appears on the character.
4. When the fish icon appears, press the "space" button again to
   attract the fish.
5. After a few repetitions, a question will appear on the screen to
   prove that you are not a bot. This question consists of 3 options, if you do not click on the
   right option, you will be kicked out of the game.
6. This loop continues like this.

I can catch this fish with OpenCV, but as I said, anti-cheat prevents keys or any mouse clicks.

These clicks;

1. Python Modules;

   - PyAuotit (it didn't work)
   - PyAutogui (it didn't work)
   - AutoPy (it didn't work)
   - PyNput (it didn't work)
   - PyWinAuto (it didn't work)
   - PyDirectinput (it didn't work)
   - Win32con (it didn't work)
2. MacroRecorder v2; (it didn't work)
3. Autoit; (it didn't work)
4. Corsair ICUE Software (it worked)

Yes, the ICUE software allows me to make keyboard inputs and mouse clicks, but it cannot integrate with python.

Is there any other way I can do keyboard inputs and mouse clicks with Python? Or can I run ICUE software integrated in languages such as python, c++?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [official python binding](https://github.com/CorsairOfficial/cue-sdk-python) for the iCUE software

Installation:

```
  pip install -U cuesdk
```

Python:

```
from cuesdk import CueSdk

sdk = CueSdk()
sdk.connect()

print(sdk.protocol_details)

print(sdk.get_devices())
```

Here's the [API reference](https://github.com/corsairofficial/cue-sdk-python/blob/master/api_reference.md)

You can use something like OpenCV to detect the events in game.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find a function in the module to handle the inputs. It's like the module is only used to make LEDs.

Comment: Can you take a look at the [C API](https://corsairofficial.github.io/cue-sdk/) then? I think the Python one is a bit incomplete.

Comment: I am a beginner with c language. can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I been trying to same thing in the metin2, pydirectinput really worked after i run powershell/cmd with administrator rights.Key inputs are working but clicks still not working, i might use steelseries drivers for mouse, i couldnt figure out yet but you can send keyboard keys.

```
from time import sleep
import pydirectinput
import pyautogui as gui
sleep(4);
pydirectinput.keyDown('w')
sleep(1)
pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
sleep(1)
gui.moveTo(300,100)
gui.click(300,100)
```